# ReactJS: Why is my custom functional toast component behaving so strangely upon attempting to automatically dismiss notification pop-ups?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, popup, toast

My custom react toast component was working well until I tried to implement automatic dismissal of notifications after a set time.

I am trying to make it so that after a set time, the pop-up "toast" notifications will have a CSS fade-out animation play and then be deleted — unless the user is hovering over that notification, in which case it will hold off on dismissing that one until the user moves their mouse off of it.

Sometimes it works properly, other times it stops displaying anything and adds the notifications back one by one, other times it... well, it just behaves in a very strange and unexpected manner.

Here is my code:

**Toast.css**

```css
.toast-container {
    font-size: 24px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}

.toast-popup {
    padding: 12px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 500px;
    border: solid #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.toast-popup:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px deepskyblue;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.success {
    background-color: #5cb85c;
}
.info {
    background-color: #5bc0de;
}
.warning {
    background-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.danger {
    background-color: #d9534f;
}

.toast-text {
    justify-self: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.toast-title {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    color: #f2f2f2;
}

.toast-message {
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
}

.toast-icon {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 10px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.toast-icon img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    fill: #f2f2f2;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.close-button {
    float: right;
    align-self: flex-start;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    opacity: 0.9;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.top-right {
    top: 2rem;
    right: 2rem;
}
.top-right-slide {
    top: 2rem;
    right: 2rem;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
    animation: toast-in-right .7s;
}

.bottom-right {
    bottom: 2rem;
    right: 2rem;
}
.bottom-right-slide {
    bottom: 2rem;
    right: 2rem;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
    animation: toast-in-right .7s;
}

.top-left {
    top: 2rem;
    left: 2rem;
}
.top-left-slide {
    top: 2rem;
    left: 2rem;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in;
    animation: toast-in-left .7s;
}

.bottom-left {
    bottom: 2rem;
    left: 2rem;
}
.bottom-left-slide {
    bottom: 2rem;
    left: 2rem;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in;
    animation: toast-in-left .7s;
}

.fadeout {
    animation: 4s linear 5s 1 normal forwards running toast-fadeout;
}

@keyframes toast-in-right {
    from { transform: translateX(100%); }
    to { transform: translateX(0); }
}

@keyframes toast-in-left {
    from { transform: translateX(-100%); }
    to { transform: translateX(0); }
}

@keyframes toast-fadeout {
    from { opacity: 0.9; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
}
```

**Toast.js** *- Please excuse the generous peppering of console.logs...*

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import icon_success from './icons/feathericons/check-circle.svg';
import icon_info from './icons/feathericons/info.svg';
import icon_warning from './icons/feathericons/alert-triangle.svg';
import icon_danger from './icons/feathericons/alert-octagon.svg';
import './Toast.css';

const Toast = (props) => {
    const {toastList, position} = props;
    const [list, setList] = useState(toastList);
    const [prevId, setPrevId] = useState(0);

    // This useEffect updates the list of toasts to display
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect()');
        console.log('useEffect() toastList:');
        console.log(toastList);
        setList([...toastList]);
    }, [toastList]);

    const markForDeletion = (toast) => {
        if( toast.isDeleting ) {
            return;
        }
        console.log(`toast ${toast.id} marked for deletion`)
        toast.isDeleting = true;
        setTimeout(() => {attemptDeletion(toast)}, 5000);
    }

    const attemptDeletion = (toast) => {
        console.log(`attempting to delete toast ${toast.id}. canDelete = ${toast.canDelete}`);
        if( toast.canDelete ) {
            deleteToast(toast.id);
        }
        else {
            console.log(`cannot delete toast ${toast.id}. `);
        }
    }

    const getIcon = (variant) => {
        switch( variant ) {
            case 'success':
                return icon_success;
                break;
            case 'info':
                return icon_info;
                break;
            case 'warning':
                return icon_warning;
                break;
            case 'danger':
                return icon_danger;
                break;
        }
    }

    const generateId = (toast) => {
        if( typeof(toast.id) === 'number' ) {
            return toast.id;
        }
        toast.id = prevId + 1;
        setPrevId(toast.id);
        return toast.id;
    }

    const deleteToast = (id) => {
        console.log(`deleting toast ${id}`);
        const deletionIdxList = list.findIndex(e => e.id === id);
        const deletionIdxToastList = toastList.findIndex(e => e.id === id);
        console.log(`deletionIdxToastList: ${deletionIdxToastList}`);
        if(deletionIdxList == null || deletionIdxList === -1) {
            console.log(`cannot find list idx of id ${id}`);
            console.log('list:');
            console.log(list);
            return;
        }
        if(deletionIdxToastList == null || deletionIdxToastList === -1) {
            console.log(`cannot find toastList idx of id ${id}`);
            console.log('toastList:');
            console.log(toastList);
            return;
        }
        
        console.log('list before deletion:');
        console.log(list);
        console.log('toastList before deletion:');
        console.log(toastList);
        console.log('list[deletionIdxList]:');
        console.log(list[deletionIdxList]);
        list.splice(deletionIdxList, 1);
        console.log('toastList[deletionIdxToastList]:');
        console.log(toastList[deletionIdxToastList]);
        toastList.splice(deletionIdxToastList, 1);
        setList([...list]);
        console.log(`toast ${id} deleted successfully`);
        console.log('list after deletion:');
        console.log(list);
        console.log('toastList after deletion:');
        console.log(toastList);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className={`toast-container ${position}`} >
                {
                    list.map((toast, i) => (
                        <div
                            key={i}
                            className={`toast-popup ${toast.variant} ${toast.isDeleting ? (position + ' fadeout') : (position + '-slide')}`}
                            onLoad={() => {
                                if( !toast.isLoaded ) {
                                    toast.Id = generateId(toast);
                                    toast.canDelete = true;
                                    toast.isDeleting = false;
                                    toast.isLoaded = true;
                                    console.log(`on load ${toast.id}`);
                                    setTimeout(() => markForDeletion(toast), 500);
                                }
                            }}
                            onMouseOver={() => {
                                toast.canDelete === true ? toast.canDelete = false : null;
                                toast.isDeleting === true ? toast.isDeleting = false : null;
                                console.log(`mouse over ${toast.id}`);
                            }}
                            onMouseLeave={() => {
                                toast.canDelete === false ? toast.canDelete = true : null;
                                markForDeletion(toast);
                                console.log(`mouse leave ${toast.id}`);
                            }}
                        >
                            <div className={'toast-icon'}>
                                <img src={getIcon(toast.variant)} />
                            </div>
                            <div className={'toast-text'}>
                                <div className={'toast-title'}>
                                    {toast.variant.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + toast.variant.slice(1)}
                                </div>
                                <div className={'toast-message'}>{toast.message}</div>
                            </div>
                            <button
                                className={'close-button'}
                                onClick={() => {
                                    toast.canDelete = true;
                                    deleteToast(toast.id)
                                }
                            }>
                                X
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

Toast.defaultProps = {
    position: 'bottom-right'
}

export default Toast;
```

**Snippet of Home.js where I am testing this new Toast component** *- A class component as I'm working on updating a pre-existing application to remove dependency on the react-toastify library*

```js
// Leaving out constructor and other irrelevant code...
  toastSuccess() {
    const newToast = {
      variant: 'success',
      message: 'This is a test of the success variant toast pop-up.'
    }
    this.setState({
      toastList: [...this.state.toastList, newToast]
    });
  }
  toastInfo() {
    const newToast = {
      variant: 'info',
      message: 'This is a test of the info variant toast pop-up.'
    }
    this.setState({
      toastList: [...this.state.toastList, newToast]
    });
  }
  toastWarning() {
    const newToast = {
      variant: 'warning',
      message: 'This is a test of the warning variant toast pop-up.'
    }
    this.setState({
      toastList: [...this.state.toastList, newToast]
    });
  }
  toastDanger() {
    const newToast = {
      variant: 'danger',
      message: 'This is a test of the danger variant toast pop-up.'
    }
    this.setState({
      toastList: [...this.state.toastList, newToast]
    });
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div className="Home" style={{height:'100%'}}>
        <Toast
            toastList={this.state.toastList}
            position={'bottom-right'}
        />
        <div style={{display:'flex', justifyContent:'center'}}>
          <Button onClick={() => this.toastSuccess()}>Success</Button>
          <Button onClick={() => this.toastInfo()}>Info</Button>
          <Button onClick={() => this.toastWarning()}>Warning</Button>
          <Button onClick={() => this.toastDanger()}>Danger</Button>
        </div>
        {// ...}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Let me know if there's a way to get this code running here on StackOverflow using that Code Snippet feature, as that would be really helpful so that you readers can see the issue first-hand. Unfortunately I've never had any luck getting it to work, but I'll keep trying for a bit to see if I can figure it out.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Cristian-FlorinCalina for recommending StackBlitz as a good shareable test environment. I've got it set up there now, here's a link:
https://react-ts-ybunlg.stackblitz.io

Comment: you can add a stackblitz link with your code working there

Comment: Thanks @Cristian-FlorinCalina for the recommendation, I've got the link added to the end of my post now

Comment: Just one quesiton: is it a requirement to implement your own version? Or are you doing it to experiment? Because there are already production grade packages for this such as react-toastify (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify)

Comment: @Cristian-FlorinCalina It's a requirement as my team and I are trying to remove as many dependencies from our application as possible. Although it has been a fun experiment regardless and I've learned a bit about CSS animations and functional components in the process.

Comment: We actually were using react-toastify and this is my work-in-progress attempt at making a replacement for it :)

Answer (score 1):

First problem that I see with your code is that you are keeping two sources of truth for toast list. One is passed from the parent via `props`, and one is the internal state list in the `Toast` component. This is an antipattern that can generate a lot of issues.

Second **BIG** issue is that you are altering the list that you receive from the parent. That is a huge antipattern in `React` since `props` are [readonly](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only) -- **All React components must act like pure functions with respect to their props.** (since you are altering an object inside an array apparently it works for the load update but it does not work when you are trying to call splice on the list -- this is why even if you deleted the element and applied the deletion effect, when it gets updated on the parent (next render) -> it will come back without it being removed and clicking again on another toast generate button will show you the previously deleted toast as well).

I think the big problem here is that you are not using composition properly. Instead of passing the toast list to the `Toast` component, you should keep the list on the parent, move the `map` from the child inside the parent. You will have one instance of `Toast` component per each element in the list.

Maybe you can have a `ToastList` component as well, that handles `Toast` compoonents based on their position... So when you click on `Upper Left Toast Generator` for example, it will add a new entry inside an array of toasts, with a `position` key. That array will be sent to the `ToastList` component, which will generate `Toast` components that handle their state internally (deletion, etc) and do not update the actual list. You can pass a function to the `Toast` component called `onDelete` that will be called by the `Toast` component on deletion, and you will update the `ToastList` state based on those events (probably propagate the delete event to the parent to update the list there).

Hope it makes sense.